# Ember.js equivalent of .difference?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Does Ember have a .difference function [like underscore does](http://underscorejs.org/#difference)? I have an `ArrayController` with a set of objects in each one. I want to subtract all the objects in `ArrayController2` from `ArrayController1` :

```
ArrayController1:
   1
   2
   3
   4

ArrayController2:
   2
   4
```

Then do the difference:

```
ArrayController1.difference(ArrayController2) => 1
                                                 3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is an single method that will do that, but you could write a helper that essentially did the following:

```
array1.reject((function(item) {
  return array2.contains(item);
}), array2);
```

Just looping through array1 and rejecting anything that returns true for array2.contains().

Answer (score 1):

5 years late but there's a computed function `setDiff` which you can use to achieve what you want.

```
import { setDiff } from '@ember/object/computed';
...
ArrayDifference: setDiff('ArrayController1', 'ArrayController2') // [1, 3]
```

https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.18/functions/@ember%2Fobject%2Fcomputed/setDiff